# Delay in Moq return for async method not delaying

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, moq

In my unit test, I'm trying to mock out the `Run()` async method from my interface `IPipeline` and simulate a delay, where it is called in the class `PipelineScheduler`

```
public interface IPipeline
{
    Task Run();
}
```

Test Moq:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _mockPipeline = new Mock<IPipeline>();

    _mockPipeline.Setup(x => x.Run()).Returns(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    });
    _scheduler = new PipelineScheduler(_mockPipeline.Object);
}
```

However when I run the test and debug where the mocked method is called

```
await _pipeline.Run().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

there is no delay and execution continues after this line immediately.

But if I replace the mock with a stub class, the delay works fine.

```
private class MockPipeline : IPipeline
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _mockPipeline = new MockPipeline();
    _scheduler = new PipelineScheduler(_mockPipeline);
}
```

So I suppose the question is what's different from how I'm creating the delay with moq vs my stubbed class?

Comment: `.Returns(Task.Delay(3000));` is all that is needed for the the setup to behave a desired. The previous setup is a fire and forget `async void`

Comment: Then that is the answer, still can't see what is missing from the question. Perhaps it could be tweaked a little, but the main body is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the setup is being configured incorrectly.

Returning a Task *i.e*:`.Returns(Task.Delay(3000));` is all that is needed for the the setup to behave a desired. The previous setup is a fire and forget `async void` which is why the previous example did not wait and continued immediately.

The following minimal example demonstrates how the mock should have been setup

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        var _mockPipeline = new Mock<IPipeline>();

        _mockPipeline.Setup(x => x.Run()).Returns(Task.Delay(3000)).Verifiable();

        var sut = new PipelineScheduler(_mockPipeline.Object);

        //Act
        await sut.MethodUnderTest();

        //Assert
        _mockPipeline.Verify();
    }
}

public interface IPipeline {
    Task Run();
}

public class PipelineScheduler {
    private IPipeline _pipeline;

    public PipelineScheduler(IPipeline pipeline) {
        this._pipeline = pipeline;
    }

    public async Task MethodUnderTest() {

        await _pipeline.Run().ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
}
```

When exercised, the test delays for the configured 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I just had the problem and the correct way is **not** the accepted answer. The correct way is to use a function in the return.

*i.e.*

```
.Returns(() => Task.Delay(3000))
```

Without the `() =>`, the Delay is only applied once, even if you do multiple sequential calls, for example, like if you did this :

```
await _pipeline.Run().ConfigureAwait(false);
await _pipeline.Run().ConfigureAwait(false);
await _pipeline.Run().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

See this [reproduction](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fFb1h0) on dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: (Without the `() =>`, the Delay is only applied once) is gold